# Is there a way to determine the source of an "auto" css property using Browser Developer Tools

Tags: html, css

I have a complicated page where the width:auto returns a width that is smaller than I think it should be for several of the divs.  If I go to the Computed section in Developer Tools, I can see where the width for a given element is obtained by css line (this usually points to a line for a given element that says width:auto.  If the width is a smaller number derived elsewhere though, it is grayed out.  Is there a way to see where in the cascade that that width is determined more absolutely?

Comment: no because width can be affected by a lot of properties (even ones applied to a parent element) so you need to understand your layout to identify the issue

Comment: I certainly understand that, and agree.  Its always easier when building from scratch. . .but sometimes the way properties interact is not contained to the page in question. . .consider the useragent style sheet or a bootstrap element.  I guess what I am wondering is. . .if css is calculated based on a known flow. . .how is it that that is not inherently traceable in the Developer tools window.  Seems like all of the information needed is there.  Its extremely helpful. . .its hard to imagine the developers of the "browser developer tools" would not have thought to include that capability.